# EvaluateJsonPath creates additional flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

So Im using EvaluateJsonPath to extract three json values to attributes but I ran into this issue where when there's one flowfile it turns into three with same filename but different UUIDs after processing through EvaluateJsonPath. Is this how it's supposed to work or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

I have 'flowfile-attribute' setup as Destination field value

[image]

Comment: Show `EvaluateJsonPath` processor properties

Answer (score 0):

It had to be some kind of bug, I added another exactly same processor and it works with no issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).